# Design pattern for multiple DAC and SAC calls

Tags: c#, design-patterns

**Scenario**- After request validation, I will need to

1. Call database and update the record. Based on a certain condition on the execution of this database call and request data, I will be calling **Service1**.
2. Upon performing this step, I will call another database and update record from the request.
3. At last I will call **audit service** to save the transaction details.

This can be achievable in normal code structure. But I am pretty confident there will be plug and play after step 1 or 2, i.e., a database/service call will be introduced in next release after step 1/step 2 (TBD).

I decided to opt for **Chain of Responsibility**.

**Problems**

1. Where ever the operation breaks/exception is generated, code should stop its execution.
2. Under single Logging object, I am having difficulty to handle the sequential call.
3. For step 1’s conditional service call, the dynamic modification of the chain of operations is bit complex, as I have to rely on single data type return from the AbstractionHandler.

Is there any alternative design pattern that I can follow?

Comment: Your question kinda sounds like _code design and/or improvement_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a scenario in which you have a sequence of operations that may or may not occur based on the result of previous operations.

In my opinion you choosing the right pattern, Chain of Responsibility will be a good choice.

You just need to adapt the classic implementaion that allows passing the request along the chain of potential handlers until one of them handles request.

Basicaly, you can change the implementation of each operation so that when its condition is valid, it executes its own logic and returns the result for the next operation in the chain.

So where ever the operation fail, you should't throw exceptions because exceptions must be used for exceptional conditions (any condition that your normal logical flow does not handle); therefore, within a chain of responsibility it is expect that some operation could return a signal to interrupt the chain (expected result).

Considering that, in my opinion you shouldn't throw an exception in this situation. Instead, you should return a controlled signal to stop the flow of the chain.

Regards,

Comment: But how do I dynamically control the call to Service1, that’s based on the first dac success result and a condition?

Comment: @PrateekGangopadhyay you can pass result of your call to Service1 down the chain